# Create draggables by dragging mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I am new to JQuery library. I am currently trying to create a Draggable by mouse. Say, when I press the mouse it start to draw and then I drag the mouse to change the size and then I release the mouse to finalize the drawing.

Is it possible to do this with JQuery?

Comment: Do you mean like resizing a container or something by dragging an edge with the mouse?

Comment: Or like a canvas where you draw rectangles by click and drag?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't describe my question clear enough. I mean like a canvas where I can draw rectangles by click and drag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.

If your are interested in drag and drop, look here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback

This is jQuery UI, which is a library for jQuery, that provides many interesting UI widgets (see more here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you asked: http://jsbin.com/azare

It's rough, but hey.

Comment: Hi wombleton, this is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your help. 

Joe